# Arquillian bean and dao @Injection don't work

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I'm writing wildfly Java EE app but i have problem with bean injection in testcases. It don't work in standalone tests and in ShrinkWrap deployed also.

```
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import javax.inject.Inject;
...


@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class InjectionTestCase {
    @org.jboss.arquillian.core.api.annotation.Inject 
    private ProjectStatusDao proStatusDao;

    @Inject
    private ClientsCtrl clients;

    @Test
    public void groupSetter() {
        ManageUser user = new ManageUser();

        String g = "group";
        user.setGroup(g);

        Assert.assertEquals(g, user.getGroup());
    }
}
```

Simple test but both injected objects are null. I tried injection from org.jboss.arquillian.core.api.annotation.Inject package but the same effect.

Can you help me? I have no idea what to do with that.

src/test/resources/arquillian.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/arquillian-1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.jboss.org/arquillian-1.0
      http://www.jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian-1.0.xsd">

    <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />

    <extension qualifier="webdriver">
        <property name="browser">chrome</property>
    </extension>

    <container qualifier="widlfly-remote" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="managementAddress">host</property>
            <property name="managementPort">9990</property>
            <property name="username">user</property>
            <property name="password">password</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

Execution log

```
kwi 14, 2016 8:25:02 AM org.jboss.arquillian.drone.webdriver.factory.remote.reusable.ReusedSessionPermanentFileStorage readStore
INFO: Reused session store is not available at C:\Users\......\.drone-webdriver-session-store, a new one will be created.
kwi 14, 2016 8:25:02 AM org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.RunModeUtils isRunAsClient
WARNING: The test method "InjectionTestCase groupSetter" will run on the client side - there is no running deployment yet. Please use the annotation @RunAsClient
kwi 14, 2016 8:25:02 AM org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.RunModeUtils isRunAsClient
WARNING: The test method "InjectionTestCase groupSetter" will run on the client side - there is no running deployment yet. Please use the annotation @RunAsClient
kwi 14, 2016 8:25:02 AM org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.RunModeUtils isRunAsClient
WARNING: The test method "InjectionTestCase groupSetter" will run on the client side - there is no running deployment yet. Please use the annotation @RunAsClient
kwi 14, 2016 8:25:02 AM org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.RunModeUtils isRunAsClient
WARNING: The test method "InjectionTestCase groupSetter" will run on the client side - there is no running deployment yet. Please use the annotation @RunAsClient
kwi 14, 2016 8:25:02 AM org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.RunModeUtils isRunAsClient
WARNING: The test method "InjectionTestCase groupSetter" will run on the client side - there is no running deployment yet. Please use the annotation @RunAsClient
kwi 14, 2016 8:25:02 AM org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.RunModeUtils isRunAsClient
WARNING: The test method "InjectionTestCase groupSetter" will run on the client side - there is no running deployment yet. Please use the annotation @RunAsClient
```

New logs. With ShrinkWrap:

```
public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        File[] files = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
                .importRuntimeDependencies().resolve().withTransitivity().asFile();


        WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
                // add classes
                .addPackages(true, "my.package")
                // add configuration
                .addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource(new File("src/test/webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml"))
                // add pages
                .addAsWebResource(new File("src/main/webapp/403.xhtml"))
                .addAsWebResource(new File("src/main/webapp/404.xhtml"))
                .addAsWebResource(new File("src/main/webapp/error.xhtml"))
                .addAsWebResource(new File("src/main/webapp/login.xhtml"))
                /** OTHER PAGES ADDED **/

                // add libraries
                .addAsLibraries(files)

                .setWebXML(new File("src/test/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml"));                

        System.err.println(war.toString(true));

        return war;
}

@Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        return createDeployment();
    }
```

I found one problem. Tests are trying to connect with 0.0.0.0 instead of my extrnal wildfly server "host"

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error launching request at http://0.0.0.0:8080/test/ArquillianServletRunner?outputMode=serializedObject&className=my.package.InjectionTestCase&methodName=groupSetter. No result returned
```

On server i see that application is deployed succesfully

```
2016-04-15 11:20:55,986 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "test.war" (runtime-name: "test.war")
......
2016-04-15 11:21:00,884 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS018559: Deployed "test.war" (runtime-name : "test.war")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must Arquillian tell, that you want to deploy your Testcase on a server:

Simple example(without addPackages() and so on)

```
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
  JavaArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class).addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE,
            "beans.xml");
   return archive;
}
```

Depending on your project you may include some extra deploy operations:

```
    EnterpriseArchive ear = ShrinkWrap.create(EnterpriseArchive.class, "TestProject.ear")
            .addAsModule(archive);
    archive.addAsResource("resources/MANIFEST.MF", "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
    archive.addAsResource("resources/beans.xml", "META-INF/beans.xml");
    archive.addAsResource("resources/persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml");
```

And then on the server the whole Dependency Injection should work or at least the test-deployment should fail with an appropriate message

EDIT:

Regarding the

```
  Error launching request at.....
```

Error:

According to this:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Container+configuration

try to add

```
        <property name="host">yourhost</property>
        <property name="port">8181</property>
```

to the configuration in your arquillian.xml

Comment: I added ShrinkWrap but new problem occured. Logs and code added to first post.

Comment: It looks like it work. Now injected entity is not a null. Thanks @Jan_Piel. Now i have "Unexpected callable present in Drone Context, should be already instantiated at this moment". I'm trying to find solution for that. Thanks for help. It blocked me for a few days. Could problem with "Drone Context" be because i have remote server without graphial env?

Comment: Sorry, I've got no experience with the  Arquillian Drone Extension

Comment: I figure it out. I removed "testable=false" from Deployment annotation and for GUI tests RunAsClient annotation need to be added. RunAsClient should be added only for GUI tests. If i add those annotation to DAO tests then injection don't work. Anyway, thanks for help. Without you, I would not move further.

Comment: You cannot @Inject anything what is deployed to the container if you run your tests in the client mode, as they are executed outside of the container. This is exactly what you need for running Drone (or any sort of black box tests for that matter). I cannot imagine running Firefox driver from within the application container :)

Comment: You can do however a gray-box testing approach with Arquillian Warp. This lets you exercise your test from the outside, but also execute some verification from within the container where you in fact can inject your DAOs. Readme in the repo has quite a bit of explanation what you can do with Warp. https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-warp

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import the correct Annotation:

```
org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment
```

And not this one:

```
org.jboss.arquillian.api.Deployment;
```

The second one will not be picked up and give the same error

```
there is no running deployment yet. Please use the annotation @RunAsClient
```